# PyQt5: Using DeleteOnClose when switching to new window

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, spyder

I am currently creating a GUI in Python 3.7, using PyQt5 and Qt Designer in the Spyder environment. The GUI has many different windows. Basically I am starting with the UI_Start window and then open the next window when a button is pressed. The GUI is working kind of fine, however after approximately 50 windows the program suddenly doesn't show the next window anymore but also doesn't stop the execution. The weird thing about this issue is that:

1. the exact same window class has been called a lot of times beforehand and there have never been any issues
2. the problem does not only occur for one window but it can also occur for another window class (but after the same amount of windows being shown)

I tried to figure out why the .show() command is suddenly not working anymore. I used print statements to see where the program "breaks down". I saw that even the print statements after the .show() command are working but then as the window isn't shown I can't press any button to trigger the next event. So basically the program is hanging.

I am relatively new to programming in Python and creating GUIs but I thought that maybe the problem occurs due to memory leak. This is why I am now trying to open memory space when closing a window by using self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True). However, now I am facing the problem that the next window doesn't show up anymore. So how can I use DeleteOnClose if I want to show a new window afterwards?

Also if anyone has a suggestion for the original problem, please let me know. I am trying to figure out the problem since like a week but have not come any further.

Thank you already!

Some part of my code to work with:

```
class UI_Start(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UI_Start, self).__init__() # Call the inherited classes __init__ method
        uic.loadUi('Screen_Start.ui', self) # Load the .ui file
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)   # added newly
        self.Start_pushButton_Start.clicked.connect(self.openKommiScreen)
        
        
    def openKommiScreen(self):
        self.close()
        self.KommiScreen = UI_Kommi(self)  
        
        
class UI_Kommi(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):  
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(UI_Kommi, self).__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi('Screen_Kommi.ui', self)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)
        global sheetNo
        sheetNo = 1
        self.WeiterButton = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton,'pushButton_Weiter')
        self.WeiterButton.clicked.connect(self.openScanScreen)
        self.show()
        
        
    def openScanScreen(self):
        self.close()
        self.ScanScreen = UI_Scan(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = UI_Start()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You say that you're facing this issue after about 50 windows opened, but according to your code there's no way to achieve that (since you always close the current window before showing the next one); also, there's no code related to `UI_Scan`. Please always try to provide [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (we *must* be able to *reproduce* your issue!). Also, using global is rarely a good idea. I'd suggest you to edit your code and provide a MRE (carefully read the link above), as the accepted answer is probably not a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I would guess it's a garbage collection problem. The only reference to your new window is stored in your previous one. Which is deleted, so there is no more reference to your window object and python may delete it automatically.

In these cases I often goes for a global variable to store the current windows references.